# Entity Framework Code First Relationship Without Foreign Key

Tags: entity-framework, code-first

I'm new to ORM tools and I want to do relationships between tables only with naming convention. For example if I have classes like below;

```
public class City
{
    public int Id;
    public string Name;
}

public class District 
{
    public int Id;
    public string Name;
    public City City;
}
```

I want to map these classes in my database like this.

```
City
   Id int,
   Name nvarchar(100)

District
   Id int,
   Name nvarchar(100),
   CityId int
```

I don't want to use foreign keys and when I put any class as a property in another class I want to migrate these property as "ClassNameId". Any solution for this ?

Answer (score 0):

Your design for relationship is not correct to use EF.

the correct relationship is

```
public class City
{
    public int Id;
    public string Name;

    public virtual ICollection<District> Districts;
}

public class District 
{
    public int Id;
    public string Name;
    public int CityId;
    public virtual City City;
}
```

and in entity configuration you need to make in city definition on your EntityTypeConfiguration :

```
  public DistrictConfiguration()
        {
            HasKey(a => a.Id);

            HasRequired(a => a.City)
                .WithMany(a => a.Districts)
                .HasForeignKey(a => a.CityId);


             ToTable("District");
        }
```

Comment: If do the configuration like this EF will create foreign key in DB i think. Am I wrong?

Comment: I make changes in model, because is the inverse of i think before, see the structure, the entity District need a Key to make relation to City, if you not specify, EF creates with EF names default specifications.

Comment: Thanks for your reply and update. Bıt it's not important for me which entity is related with another. My problem is that I don't want to use foreign key constraints and for example if I query a district I want to get city of district in its attribute @NIZZOLA

Comment: If you don´t want to use fk, the relationship of EF not works ! Many times if i forget to do the correct specification, the EF create fields to improve this.

Comment: if i'm not mistaken with Nhibernate it is possible to create relation with no foreignkey constraint. I wonder that EF has ability for this purpose.